# I keep getting a repeat error I can't solve

Tags: python

I want to remote control my Devastator tank powered with RPi B3, PiHut MotorShield and mini WiFi keyboard.I am stuck with error "setupterm cannot find keyboard" Here is my code.

```
import curses  
import PiMotor 
import time
import curses
import os  # added so we can shutdown OK

#Name of Individual MOTORS
m1 = PiMotor.Motor("MOTOR1",1)
m2 = PiMotor.Motor("MOTOR2",1)

#To drive all motors together
motorAll = PiMotor.LinkedMotors(m1,m2)

#Names for Individual Arrows
ab = PiMotor.Arrow(1)
al = PiMotor.Arrow(2)
af = PiMotor.Arrow(3) 
ar = PiMotor.Arrow(4)

# Get the curses window, turn off echoing of keyboard to screen, turn off     
# instant (no waiting) key response, and use special values for curser keys
screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(True)

##This segment drives the motors in the direction listed below:
## forward and reverse takes speed in percentage(0-100)

try:
    while True:
        char = screen.getch()
        if char == ord('q'):
            break
        if char == ord('S'):  # Added for shutdown on capital S
            os.system ('sudo shutdown now')   # shutdown right now!
        elif char == curses.KEY_UP:
            af.on()
            motorAll.forward(100) 
        elif char == curses.KEY_DOWN:
            af.off()
            ab.on()
            motorAll.reverse(100) 
        elif char == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
            ar.on()
            ab.off()
            m1.reverse(100)
            m2.forward(100)
        elif char == curses.KEY_LEFT:
            ar.off()
            al.on()
            m1.forward(100)
            m2.reverse(100)
        elif char == 10:
            motorALL.stop()

except KeyboardInterupt:
    #Close down curses properly, inc turn echo back on!
    curses.nobreak(); screen.keypad(0); curses.echo(0)
    curses.endwin()
```

I have used "curses" with mini keyboard before but this time I  can't fix this error.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the difference between the code that works and this code here?

Comment: In the code that works I am using adifferent driver and GPIO pin numbers instead of Motor definitions. Motor definitions come with MotorShield driver library.